# What are the physics principles behind magnetic strength and distances

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

This is for my report and I wanna know what are the theory behind why magnets repel. Why magnetic force decreases as distance increases. I wrote down one of the theory, magnetic field but I'm not sure what are the other theories are behind this. (I did two experiments, one of them is magnetic spring)

Also how does length of a magnet affect magnetic strength and distance?

Comment: How familiar are you with electric fields or gravity? Magnetism can be thought of as just yet another field force acting over a distance. The farther away, the weaker because the same "strength" is spread out over a larger area.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with electric fields or gravity. I'm currently a Year 12 student. I've conducted an experiment on magnetic strength vs distance, I measured the repelling force of two magnets (same strength and size), the resulting graph resembles an exponential function. I've also done the magnetic spring experiment and same principle applied. Magnetic strength increases as distance decreases. I've conducted research online and came across with different theory, like inverse square law, inverse cube law explaining why magnetic strength falls off with distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simpler way of explanation, a magnet is considered to resemble an eleclectic dipole. Like an electric dipole, a magnet is considered to have positive and negative poles ( that is,  here , having negative and positive magnetic charges at either ends of the magnet ). When two magnets interact each other, these negative and positive charges attracts and repels each other depending on their respective  charges and dI stance between them. The net attraction and repulsion is estimated by calculating the net force on the magnet.Here, Columbs law ( used for determining electric force between two electric charges ) is valid with the electric charges in the equation replaced by the magnetic charges.

[image]

As of electric charges, like magnetic charges repel each other and unlike magnetic charges repels each other.

[image]

This i guess will help you understand. As noted, this isn't an accurate theory and is just theoretical,   not practical. This I guess is apt for you as you are not that familiar with electric and magnetic forces.

The distance relation you asked is experimentally derived as you did,  and the equations are developed based on those experiments.

Comment: So what are the concepts/physics principle lies behind this phenomenon?

Comment: The phenomenon  related to magnetic charges?  If that's what you are asking about, then, magnetic charges or magnetic monopoles are just for theoretical use or for simpler explanation and not real. They help you understand magnets more easily by comparing them with electrical dipoles( which consist of a negative and a positive charge seperately by a particular distance). They concepts you require to know here is columb's force, the related equation. Here, the electric charges in Columbs equation is replaced by magnetic charges.

Comment: This would be of more help for you : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have a better understanding of the concepts now!